# How to process multiple touch swipes unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a fairly new programmer and after learning my c# basics i am trying to get into game development with Unity. Right now i am coding a small mobile game. I want to add an one screen multiplayer to it. I had an easy script set up which gathered the starting and ending position of the swipe and calculated the path between the two points. then it compared the absolute of Δx with the absolute of Δy and finally it testet whether the coordinate is below or above 0. this works quite nicely but obviously it would not work for my planned one screen multiplayer. first i tried just testing whether the starting point of a swipe is located to the left or right of the screen center. this also worked quite nicely but it could obviously not track two swipes at the same time. then i tried changing the variables to arrays and adding a for (later a foreach loop). now whenever i swipe in one direction it repeats the signal every frame even if i clear the slot in the array at the beginning of the loop... after literally one and a half days of trying stuff out and searching for answers i now came around to adding my own question. thank you in advance.

```
public class HopefullyWorkingSwipeDetector
{
    Vector2[] av2_TouchPos1L = new Vector2[5];
    Vector2[] av2_TouchPos2L = new Vector2[5];
    Vector2[] av2_TouchPathL = new Vector2[5];
    public int[] aint_TouchDirectionL = new int[5]; // Up: 0; Down: 1; Right: 2; Left: 3; n/a: 4;
    public int int_SwipePendingL;

    public int int_CountTouchesL = 0;

    public void ListenForSwipeP1()
    {
        int_CountTouchesL = 0;
        int_SwipePendingL = 0;

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(int_CountTouchesL).phase == TouchPhase.Began && Input.GetTouch(int_CountTouchesL).position.x < Screen.width / 2)
            {
                int_SwipePendingL = int_CountTouchesL;
                av2_TouchPos1L[int_SwipePendingL] = Input.GetTouch(int_SwipePendingL).position;
            }
            else if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(int_SwipePendingL).phase == TouchPhase.Ended && Input.GetTouch(int_SwipePendingL).position.x < Screen.width / 2)
            {
                av2_TouchPos2L[int_SwipePendingL] = Input.GetTouch(int_SwipePendingL).position;
                av2_TouchPathL[int_SwipePendingL] = av2_TouchPos2L[int_SwipePendingL] - av2_TouchPos1L[int_SwipePendingL];

                if (Mathf.Abs(av2_TouchPathL[int_SwipePendingL].x) < Mathf.Abs(av2_TouchPathL[int_SwipePendingL].y)) //Vertical
                {
                    if (av2_TouchPathL[int_SwipePendingL].y > 0) //up
                    {
                        aint_TouchDirectionL[int_SwipePendingL] = 0;
                    }
                    else if (av2_TouchPathL[int_SwipePendingL].y < 0) //Down
                    {
                        aint_TouchDirectionL[int_SwipePendingL] = 1;
                    }

                }
                else if (Mathf.Abs(av2_TouchPathL[int_SwipePendingL].x) > Mathf.Abs(av2_TouchPathL[int_SwipePendingL].y)) //horizontal
                {
                    if (av2_TouchPathL[int_SwipePendingL].x > 0) //Right
                    {
                        aint_TouchDirectionL[int_SwipePendingL] = 2;
                    }
                    else if (av2_TouchPathL[int_SwipePendingL].x < 0) //left
                    {
                        aint_TouchDirectionL[int_SwipePendingL] = 3;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                aint_TouchDirectionL[int_CountTouchesL] = 4;
            }



            int_CountTouchesL++;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You need a dictionary or List to store the touchid. Each touchid should be mapped to a struct or class that contains the touchid data like the begin and end touch positions. The data is added to the dictionary or List on touch down/enter and remove on touch up/released. Hopefully, this will help you re-write your code.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get it to work. with this solution.